# How to show download link for ir.attachment in Kanban card for Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, kanban

I want to show the download link for ir.attachment in Kanban card (as in the form view), below the attachment name. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url widget.

```
 <field name="url" widget="url"/>
```

[Example](http://gitlab.opengest.solutions/opengest/odoo/blob/b4579339c8cfb9bf4111359717939dc9a12ac43e/addons/google_spreadsheet/views/google_spreadsheet_views.xml#L26)

Comment: Another exemple: http://gitlab.opengest.solutions/opengest/odoo/blob/b4579339c8cfb9bf4111359717939dc9a12ac43e/addons/auth_signup/views/res_users_views.xml#L29